# java - looking a method like contains

Tags: java, contain

```
  static boolean contains(Iterable<String> haystack, String needle) {
    for (String s : haystack) {
        if (s.contains(needle)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  static void containsAll() throws IOException {
    List<String> words = loadLines("opacial.txt");
    List<String> tocheck = loadLines("queries0.txt");
    System.out.println(words.size());
    System.out.println(tocheck.size());
    int index2 = 0;
    for (String s : tocheck) {
      if (contains(words, s)) {
          index2++;
          //return false;

      }

     }
    System.out.println(index2);
    //return true;
  }
```

i am looking a method like contains (code above) that will do this:
it will check if needle exists in the haystack, or if needle is part of a string in haystack.
In that case (the code above) if i reverse the file that goes to haystack, and the file that gives the needle, the result is the same. but i dont want that. for example:

```
File 1: 
i love beers
i like travelling
stackoverflow
beers

And File2 :    
beers
i love stackoverflow
```

then if haystack comes from file 1 and needle comes from file2, i want the result to be 2 because the word beers is part-or the same only with two strings of haystack. (beers ---> i love beers and beers) - nothing happens with i love stackoverflow)
BUT when haystack comes from file2 and needle comes from file1, i want the result to be 2. (i love beers is not part or same with anything of file 2, i like travelling the same, stackoverflow is part of i love stackoverflow -1- and finally beers is same with beers -2-) 
what is the correct method for that? 
As i said before contains gives me the same result no matter what file is haystack or gives the needle's strings.

PS in my example the result is the same, but i think that is random.

how can i do that?

Comment: How is the result same in both cases? If File 1 is haystack then result has one line, if File 2 is haystack then result has two lines.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, what is the usecase?

Comment: It looks like you have some code 'around' your 'contains' function. The result does not do what you want. You need to figure out whether the 'contains' function is not doing what you want, or the code around it is wrong. A good way to do this is writing unit tests for the 'contains' function.

Comment: Can you post code on how you are constructing the haystack (Iterable<String> haystack) I suspect it is a collection of individual words instead of phrases

Comment: the use case is what i said in the end.. i want to make the comparison i write above. if file1 is haystack i will have 2 lines,words will change with other method i didnt write.. but never mind dont look my code.. just what i wrote below about the comparison i want

Comment: OK i post more code to see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you meant that the values should probably be different for the two cases?  You show them as being the same.

If you want to find a string within another string, use the String object's indexOf method.  For example:

```
String s = "abcdef";
s.indexOf("b");
```

will return 1.  If the value is not present, the method returns -1.

So if you want to find a needle in a haystack, it means checking every line one file for the existence of a line in another file.  Keep in mind that if the files (and the lines in them) are large, this means a lot of string processing, which can be slow.  And you would have to do it in both directions.  First, get a line in file 1, and compare it to every line in file 2 (unless you find a match, in which case you can stop looking for the line from file 1).  Then move to the next line in file 1, etc.

The reverse, and look for line 1 from file 2 in file 1.

I won't describe all the logic, but that part shouldn't be too hard to figure out, assuming you know how to open files and write loops.